# Using RandomForest for land use classification in Google Earth Engine: Training accuracy shows error

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest, machine-learning

I am using RandomForest classification for my LULCC study. I have been successful in running the classification including getting the "validation accuracy" as 0.87. However, my "training acuracy" shows a value of "1" (which I think should be an error).

Sharing the code below:

```
//i) Merge hand-drawn polygons into one FeatureCollection: 

var FCmerged=water.merge(urban).merge(barrenland).merge(plantation).merge(nonMangrove).merge(mangrove); 
print(FCmerged.size());      //size value answer: 553
Map.addLayer(FCmerged, {}, 'FCMerged'); 


//ii) Select bands to be used for classification: 
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4','B5','NDWI','NDVI'];
//print(bands,'bands');   


//iii) Using Stratified RandomSampling to generate training points within the polygons: 
var FCimage=ee.Image().byte().paint(FCmerged, "lc").rename("lc")
//print(FCimage, 'image'); 

var stratifiedsample=FCimage.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints:1000, 
  classBand:"lc",
  region:ROI,
  scale:30, 
  classValues:[0,1,2,3,4,5], 
  classPoints:[150,150,150,150,150,150],
  geometries:true
}) 

// iv) Collect and map training points: 
print('Stratified samples',stratifiedsample); 
print(stratifiedsample.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),['lc']).get('histogram','No of points'));     //'Stratified samples' answer: 900 elements, 1 column

//v) Extract pixel values of the training points:

var trainingPoints=l8.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection:stratifiedsample,
  properties:["lc"],
  geometries:true,
  scale:30,
})
print(trainingPoints,{},'trainingPoints');   // trainingPoints answer: 844 elements, 0 columns
Map.addLayer(trainingPoints, {},'trainingPoints',false);

 
// vi) Split the training points by 70%/30% 
var sample=trainingPoints.randomColumn();

var split = 0.7;  // Roughly 70% training, 30% testing.
var training = sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
print(training,'points for classifier');   //points for classifier answer: 569 elements, 1 column
var test = sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));
print(test,'Testing points');      //testing points answer: 275 elements, 1 column


// vii) Build the Random Forest classifier: 
var RandomForest=ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(500).train({
  features:training,
  classProperty:'lc',
  inputProperties:bands,
}); 
print('Random forest,explained', RandomForest.explain());//RandomForest answer: Object(5 properties)


//viii) Classify L8 using RandomForest:  
var L8Classified=l8.select(bands).classify(RandomForest); 
print(L8Classified, 'L8 Classified'); // this output is an image


//x) Visualisation parameters: 
var lcPalette =  [
  '0000FF', // water (0) (blue)
  'FF0000', // urban (1) (red)
  'FFFF00',//  plantation (2) (yellow)
  'FFFFFF',//barrenland (3) (white)
  '008000', // mangroveforest (4) (green)
  '1E7C19',//nonmangroveforests (5) (dark green)
];
//xi) Add Classified landcover onto map: 
Map.addLayer(L8Classified, {palette:lcPalette, min:0,max:6}, 'LULCC_2020'); 

// ix) Check the acuracy of the classification using a confusion matrix: 

var confusionMatrix = RandomForest.confusionMatrix();
print('Classification accuracy: ', confusionMatrix.accuracy());   //answer: 1

//xii) Validate the RandomForest Classification using test points: 
var testEvaluation = test.classify(RandomForest); 
print('Test Evaluation', testEvaluation);  

// Get a confusion matrix representing expected accuracy.
var testAccuracy = testEvaluation.errorMatrix('lc', 'classification');
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());  // answer: 0.86
```

Can you point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy is given on a scale of 0 to 1. So a training accuracy of 1 = 100%.

You may wish to view this sceptically and get a larger training sample, but then again you may also just have good training data. Or be over-fitting your model.